# Updating records in Postgres using FROM clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm changing my db schema, and moving column 'seat' from old_table to new_table.  First I added a 'seat' column to new_table.  Now I'm trying to populate the column with the values from old_table.

```
UPDATE new_table
SET seat = seat
FROM old_table
WHERE old_table.id = new_table.ot_id;
```

This returns ERROR:  column reference "seat" is ambiguous.

```
UPDATE new_table nt
SET nt.seat = ot.seat
FROM old_table ot
WHERE ot.id = nt.ot_id;
```

Returns ERROR:  column "nt" of relation "new_table" does not exist

Ideas?

Comment: I think this is not specific to PostgreSQL, but standard SQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE new_table
SET seat = old_table.seat
FROM old_table
WHERE old_table.id = new_table.ot_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

IIRC the table to be updated is the one that must not be aliased. Did you try this?

```
UPDATE new_table
SET seat = ot.seat
FROM old_table ot
WHERE ot.id = ot_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just mention `seat`, like so

```
UPDATE new_table nt
SET seat = ot.seat
FROM old_table ot
WHERE ot.id = nt.ot_id;
```